# MongoDB fast deletion best approach

Tags: mongodb, partitioning

My application currently use MySQL. In order to support **very** fast deletion, I organize my data in partitions, according to timestamp. Then when data becomes obsolete, I just drop the whole partition.
It works great, and cleaning up my DB doesn't harm my application performance.

I would want to replace MySQL with MongoDB, and I'm wondering if there's something similiar in MongoDB, or would I just need to delete the records one by one (which, I'm afraid, will be really slow and will make my DB busy, and slow down queries response time).

Comment: You could factor the data into time series collections based on how long it takes for data to become historical, then just `drop()` the collection

Comment: I think the major problem is MongoDB kinda sucks. And I'm not saying that to be offensive or appear like I don't know anything about how NoSQL technologies work, but there are better alternatives that serve the same purposes as MongoDB. There are 500 informative authorities on this, but here's just one: http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2013/05/13/mongo-bad-for-scraped-data/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MongoDB, if your requirement is to delete data to limit the collection size, you should use a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

On the other hand, if your requirement is to delete data based on a timestamp, then [a TTL index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) might be exactly what you're looking for.

From official doc regarding capped collections:

> Capped collections automatically remove the oldest documents in the collection without requiring scripts or explicit remove operations.

And regarding TTL indexes:

> Implemented as a special index type, TTL collections make it possible to store data in MongoDB and have the mongod automatically remove data after a specified period of time.

Answer (score 6):

I thought, even though I am late and an answer has already been accepted, I would add a little more.

The problem with capped collections is that they regularly reside upon one shard in a cluster. Even though, in latter versions of MongoDB, capped collections are shardable they normally are not. Adding to this a capped collection MUST be allocated on the spot, so if you wish to have a long history before clearing the data you might find your collection uses up significantly more space than it should.

TTL is a good answer however it is not as fast as `drop()`. TTL is basically MongoDB doing the same thing, server-side, that you would do in your application of judging when a row is historical and deleting it. If done excessively it will have a detrimental effect on performance. Not only that but it isn't good at freeing up space to your `$freelist`s which is key to stopping fragmentation in MongoDB.

`drop()`ing a collection will literally just "drop" the collection on the spot, instantly and gracefully giving that space back to MongoDB (not the OS) giving you absolutely no fragmentation what-so-ever. Not only that but the operation is a lot faster, 90% of the time, than most other alternatives.

So I would stick by my comment:

> You could factor the data into time series collections based on how long it takes for data to become historical, then just drop() the collection

#### Edit

As @Zaid pointed out, even with the `_id` field capped collections are not shardable.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but one minor observation was that [I don't think capped collections are shardable in any MongoDB version](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#recommendations-and-restrictions).

Comment: @ZaidMasud Good point out, I just assumed that hearing people talk about it on the forums and capped collections now having an _id field they could be, never actually checked to see if they were now

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is using TokuMX which supports partitioning:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/29/introducing-partitioned-collections-for-mongodb-applications/

Advantages over capped collections: capped collections use a fixed amount of space (even when you don't have this much data) and they can't be resized on-the-fly. Partitioned collections usage depends on data; you can add and remove partitions (for newly inserted data) as you see fit.

Advantages over TTL: TTL is slow, it just takes care of removing old data automatically. Partitions are fast - removing data is basically just a file removal.

HOWEVER: after getting acquired by Percona, development of TokuMX appears to have stopped (would love to be corrected on this point). Unfortunately MongoDB doesn't support this functionality and with TokuMX on its way out it looks like we will be stranded without proper solution.